# Fetching Images URL from wikipedia

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, wikipedia-api

I'm using wikipedia api to scrape images from api its returning data in json form in which the image Url is like this
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f7/Canada%27s_Aviation_Hall_of_Fame_logo.jpg"
the Url that is same for all images is "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/"
The Php code is as follows:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
if(@$_GET['search']){
    $api_url="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allimages&aifrom=".ucwords($_GET['search'])."&ailimit=500";
    $api_url=str_replace('', '%20', $api_url);
    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output=curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    preg_match_all('!//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/!', $output, $data);
    echo '<pre>';
    foreach ($data[0] as $list) {
        echo "<img src='$list'/>";
        # code...
    }

    }



?>
```

How can I get the remaining part of the url correctly?

Comment: you need to decode it first

Comment: For future reference: when stating your problem, include the unexpected results (or errors) you are getting. It helps to narrow down the problem if we know what exactly it is that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode it using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and get the url image link

```
function get_wiki_image( $search, $limit) {

  $streamContext = array(
    "ssl" => array(
          "verify_peer" => false,
          "verify_peer_name" => false,
      ),
  );

  $url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/';
  $url .= '/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allimages&aifrom=' . $search . '&ailimit=' . $limit;

  $context = stream_context_create($streamContext);

  if(FALSE === ($content = @file_get_contents($url, false,$context)) ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    $data = json_decode($content,true);
    $ret = array();
    foreach($data['query']['allimages'] as $img) {
      $ret[] = $img['url'];
    }
    return $ret;
  }

}

$search = ucwords($_GET['search']);
$images = get_wiki_image($search,500);

foreach($images as $img) {
  echo "<img src='{$img}'>";
}
```